# Naive set theory, empty set as subset of mathematical objects

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello I am self teaching foundational math, I am thinking about union of a set. It definition assumes the set to have only elements that are also sets, else it would break. But I started thinking is the empty set infact an element of any mathematical object, like say the integer n? In that case taking the union of the set  U {1,{2,3}} would yeild {2,3}
Do I understand this correctly?
Also since the integers can be constructed as sets of empty sets etc, the empty set would be an element of any integer. But does this extend to any mathematical object?

My question boils down to do union of a set imply that the set is composed of sets, or do we allow the empty set to be the result when asking for the element if any mathematical object that is not an explicit set.

Comment: The elements of a set are those "listed" in its "brace"-definition. Thus, for $A= \{ \emptyset,1,2 \}$ it is TRUE that the emptyset is an element of $A$, i.e. $\emptyset \in A$, while for $B = \{ 1,2 \}$ it is **not** TRUE that the emptyset is an element of $B$, i.e. $\emptyset \notin B$.

Comment: I dont understand your question. Basically to take the union of sets, you need at least two sets (well you can take the union of a single set, which is tantamount to taking the union of that set with the empty set, but you get the very set you started with). What are those sets in your example?

Comment: Sorry for being clear enough. Basically I was asking what would happen if you took the union of a set S where there is some element si that is not a set. Basically is the resulting set undefined, or does it ignores the union with a non set element. That's why I asked about the empty set as a way for a fallback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern treatments of set theory, for the most part *everything* is a set.

Naive set theory is—well—naive. Since it is not axiomatized or formalized in full, this question is a bit awkward to answer. But the general wisdom is that if you write $x\in y$, then $y$ is a set. Namely, only sets can have elements. This is also the case in set theories with urelements, or atoms, or objects which are not sets.

In particular, this means that if we define $\bigcup\cal A$ to be $\{a\mid\exists A\in\mathcal A:a\in A\}$, then all the non-sets objects which might exist in $\cal A$ sort of disappear. In other words, if $\bf Set$ is the collection of all sets, then $\bigcup\mathcal A=\bigcup(\mathcal A\cap\mathbf{Set})$.

The point here is that mathematics is written by humans and *for* humans. It is us who decide what to do with the end cases, or whether we ignore the exceptions or type errors, or however else we handle them. This is why mathematical texts have definitions. To formalize this sort of thing. And once you start formalizing naive set theory... you end up with a more modern treatment of it.

Comment: Aha, understand. If S ={1,2, {3}} then the union will just take the elements that exist in any subset. And if S={1,2} then it just don't have any subsets. I was to much in programming mindset. Like I wondered what if it tries to take the member of a non set. And then I thought hmm what if we define that the element of any non set is intact the empty set. And we do this by defining any non explicit set as the set with the empty set. But I realize now the definition of union does not require this.

Answer (score 2):

In a naive set theory, you typically just start with binary unions: $\{a, b, c\} \cup \{c, d, e\} = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$. The resulting set contains those (and only those) elements which appear in at least one of the input sets.

You can then extend this principle to arbitrary unions, where if you say $A_i$ is a set for all $i \in I$, then you can form $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$, which contains those (and only those) elements which appear in at least one of the $A_i$.

If you collect these $A_i$ into a single set themselves, for instance $\mathcal A = \{A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots\}$, then you can write the "union of $\mathcal A$", usually denoted $\bigcup \mathcal A$, for what we called above the union of the elements of $\mathcal A$. This is typically, as far as I know, the way the union is defined/worked with in axiomatic set theory, where everything is always a set, and thus in particular it makes sense to define the union on "the set of its operands".

To get back to your question: yes, the union operation only really makes sense when applied to (a collection of) sets. It's unclear what the union of a set and a non-set (or of two non-sets) should be. Of course, if you wanted to, you could define this to be whatever you want (including "skipping over" non-sets) but there doesn't appear to be a particular reason why you would want that definition.

> But I started thinking is the empty set infact an element of any mathematical object

No, the empty set is a *subset* of any *set*. If all your mathematical objects are sets, then the empty set is a subset of every object. However, the empty set is certainly not an *element* of every object: it's not an element of itself!

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, as a programmer I see this as a potential bug. What if you have a proof that uses the union of a set. Then you have to prove that all elements in the set you take the union on, is intact sets. That's why I wondered if the empty set was used so you ignore the union of a non set. Basically same reason 0! Is 1. So that you plug the possible holes.

Comment: To continue with the programming analogy, applying the union operation to something that is not a set can be thought of as a type error. If you're applying the union operation to something non-set-like then something has gone wrong regardless of whether you have a catch-all definition. Even in formulations of mathematics where everything is a set, this might occur; if you have two rational numbers $r, q$ then taking $r \cup q$ is usually meaningless -- even if it technically is perfectly allowed and will again be a set.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.